# Como hacer que un prompt se repita hasta que se cancele o se deje vacio?

Tags: javascript, bucles, while, prompt

Hola tengo este prompt:

```
hola = window.prompt('Como estas?');
```

Necesito repetirlo para que se guarde su contenido cuando pulse el boton de aceptar, pero si se cancela o se deja vacio debe de dejar de guardar el contenido y salir.

No se muy bien como introducir el prompt en un while para que se repita cuando necesito ya que si dejo el prompt fuera se queda sin while para repetirse, pero si lo pongo dentro no se con que comparar el while y por lo tanto no se como hacer este bucle, alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: `while (true) {hola = window.prompt('Como estás?'); if (hola == null || hola.trim() === "") { break; } }`

Answer (score 0):

De [su página en la MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt):

> #### Sintaxis
>
> `result = window.prompt( message, default );`

- `result` es una cadena de texto que contiene el valor introducido por el usuario, o null.
- `message` es una cadena de texto que se mostrará al usuario. Este parámetro es opcional y puede ser omitido si no se necesita mostrar nada en la ventana.
- `default` es una cadena de texto que contiene el valor predeterminado para el texto de entrada. Es un parámetro opcional. Nótese que en Internet Explorer 7 y 8, si no se provee un valor para este parámetro, el valor predeterminado es "undefined".

> ...
> Nótese que el resultado es una cadena de texto.
> ...
> En Safari, si el usuario presiona el botón Cancel, la función devuelve una cadena vacía.

Por lo tanto:

```js
var result;
do {
  result = prompt( 'Esto no se puede evitar' );
} while( ( typeof( result ) != 'string' ) || ( result.length == 0 ) );
```

Comment: como seria la opcion de cancelar y aceptar en js hay alguna palabra destinda a ello?

Comment: Cadena vacía si se acepta sin nada; cadena no vacía si se acepta con algo; `null` si se cancela. Pero observa que hay bastantes excepciones a ello, según el navegador.